# Null Pointer Exception while setting arraylist in struts 1.3

Tags: java, struts-1

While I thought of setting array list value to array list bean it is returning null pointer exception.
Please check action class:

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    ArrayList dailysheetdata;
    DailysheetForm dailyform = (DailysheetForm) form;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Stonecrusher?"
                        + "user=Stonecrusher&password=xxxxxx");
    System.out.println("Connection"+connect);
    dailysheetdata = StoneCrusherData.getDailysheetData(connect);
    if(dailysheetdata==null)
        System.out.println("dailysheetdata null");
    else if(dailyform==null)
    System.out.println("dailyform null");
    else
    dailyform.setArraylist(dailysheetdata) ;//iam getting exception here
    return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
     }
```

and my action form is

```
public class DailysheetForm extends ActionForm {
    // some getter and setter methods i used

    protected ArrayList arraylist;
    public ArrayList getArraylist() {
        return arraylist;
    }

    public void setArraylist(ArrayList arraylist) {

        this.arraylist = arraylist;

    }
```

When I run it I get following exception and in Tomcat log it is showing **"dailyform is null"**

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:520)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:427)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.myapp.struts.DialysheetListAction.execute(DialysheetListAction.java:59)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.
```

I am not able to find the reason. Please help to solve it and please state the reason.

Comment: Did you check your dailyform is null or not? It seems case with form is null than set arrayList

Comment: It says - **DialysheetListAction.java:59**. Did you make sure that's the line?

Comment: Which lines in the code do the NullPointerExceptions correspond with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `DailysheetForm` class object is not created by framework.

reasons are you din't configure `FormBean` class and `Action` class  are properly in `struts-config.xml`

First you should check what page(which data ?) is submitted to action class ie

```
DailysheetForm dailyform = (DailysheetForm) form;
```

check this line you are type casting `form` into `DailysheetForm` type object then framework automatically call the setter methods of `DailysheetForm` action form  so maybe here you are getting `NullPointerException` i think so  check it..

and One more thing you have to check in `struts-config.xml` entries 
 i.e in `<action> tab name attribute value` must be match with `<form-beans>` mappings 
check the package names also...